# iterate on array and return the biggest value php

Tags: php, arrays

hello everyone i have an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_max] => 2019-12-15
            [id_property] => 18
            [last_validation] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_max] => 2020-08-31
            [id_property] => 18
            [last_validation] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date_max] => 2019-12-15
            [id_property] => 21
            [last_validation] => 1
        )
  ......
)
```

what i want to do is to loop on this array and for each `id_property` i must select the max date in all occurences and return one line for each `id_property`

Example :

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [date_max] => 2019-12-15
                [id_property] => 18
                [last_validation] => 1
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [date_max] => 2020-08-31
                [id_property] => 18
                [last_validation] => 5
            )
```

for this example it should return the second occurence because date_max is the superior one.

my code so far i don't know why it's not working:

```
$data = [];

foreach ($sql as $current_key => $current_array) {
    foreach ($sql as $search_key => $search_array) {
        if (
            $current_array["id_property"] == $search_array["id_property"] &&
            $current_array["date_max"] > $search_array["date_max"]
        ) {
            array_push($data, [
                $current_array["date_max"],
                $current_array["id_property"],
                $current_array["last_validation"],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you sort it in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where you're going wrong is in the date comparison. You're only checking if one date is higher than the other. For this to work effectively you would need to have more than one record of each property id (otherwise there won't be anything to compare it to) and would assume you have it ordered by date already as it only checks one way (higher, not lower).

That being said sometimes you can cheat a bit when dealing with dates. In the example below I create an array of the records grouped by the property id using the timestamp of the date max as the array key.

Then I loop over the grouped array and pull the record with the highest key (ie the latest date):

```
$data = [];
//create array of results grouped by the property id
foreach($sql as $current_key => $current_array) {
    $ts = strtotime($current_array['date_max']); //unix timestamp from date
    $data[$current_array['id_property']][$ts]  = $current_array; //add to grouped array
}

$maxData = [];
foreach($data as $propertId=>$values) {
    ksort($values); //sort by key, highest value first
    $maxData[] = array_pop($values); //take first value
}


print_r($maxData);
```

Caveat to this method is if two records have the same date_max then you will get the last record only.

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/HsKCJ

Answer (score 1):

Here is the revised code

```
$data = [];

foreach ($arr as $current_key => $current_array) {
    $max = '';
    foreach ($arr as $search_key => $search_array) {
        if (
            $current_array["id_property"] == $search_array["id_property"] &&
            $max < $search_array["date_max"]
        ) {
            $data[$current_array["id_property"]] = [
                $current_array["date_max"],
                $current_array["id_property"],
                $current_array["last_validation"],
            ];

            $max = $search_array["date_max"];
        }
    }
}
```

Did the following changes

1. Added $max variable which is set to ' ' for every parent iteration so that every first iteration of child loop will always be true as `('' < '<any proper date>')` returns true and it will set $max value to appropriate date and will always update the $max value with the maximum date.
2. Rather than pushing array to $data I am setting the key value as $current_array["id_property"] so that it will always have the latest maximum record.

The output would be as follows.

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-08-31
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 1
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-12-15
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you first sort the array by date (using `usort()`).  Then use `array_column()` to index the array by the `id_property` value, as the index must be unique, any later values will overwrite earlier ones.

So...

```
usort($sql, function($a, $b) { 
      return $a['date_max'] <=> $b['date_max'];
});
$output = array_column($sql, null, 'id_property');
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [date_max] => 2020-08-31
            [id_property] => 18
            [last_validation] => 5
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [date_max] => 2019-12-15
            [id_property] => 21
            [last_validation] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Nice!  I was working on the same except using `array_multisort`.